# form_for params contains a blank hash for model object even though values are sent in request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

In my Rails 4 app, I have a pretty basic form:

```
<%= form_for @job, url: job_path(@job.id), html: {class: "form-horizontal group-border-dashed"} do |f| %>
        <%= f.select :client_id, options_for_select(@clients_array), { :include_blank=>false }, {class: "form-control"} %>
        <%= f.select :data_destruction, options_for_select([['Single Pass Wipe'],['Three Pass Wipe']]), { :include_blank=>false }, {class: "form-control"} %>       
        <%= f.text_field :no_items, :class => "form-control" %>
        <%= f.text_field :collection_date, class: "form-control datepicker" %>
        <%= f.select :priority, options_for_select([['Low'],['Medium'],['High'],['Urgent']]), { :include_blank=>false }, {class: "form-control"} %>                 
        <%= f.text_area :warehouse_notes, class: "form-control" %>
        <%= f.text_area :admin_notes, class: "form-control" %>
        <%= f.select :reporting_required, options_for_select([['Yes'],['No']]), { :include_blank=>false }, {class: "form-control"} %>                                   
        <%= f.text_field :contact_user, class: "form-control" %>
        <%= f.text_field :third_party_destruction, class: "form-control" %>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
<% end %>
```

When the form is submitted, it routes correctly to Jobs#Update. However, the `params[:job]` hash is empty:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "_method"=>"patch", "authenticity_token"=>"KyJebi85lhfUV/klwa2icmniravyif/REF8HD+tI5GM=", "job"=>{}, "action"=>"update", "controller"=>"jobs", "id"=>"17"}
```

However, when I inspect `request.request_parameters`, I can see that the params were sent correctly:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "_method"=>"patch", "authenticity_token"=>"KyJebi85lhfUV/klwa2icmniravyif/REF8HD+tI5GM=", "job"=>{"client_id"=>"25", "data_destruction"=>"Single Pass Wipe", "no_items"=>"1500", "collection_date"=>"", "priority"=>"Low", "warehouse_notes"=>"Sample Warehouse Notes333", "admin_notes"=>"Sample Notes", "reporting_required"=>"Yes", "contact_user"=>"user5", "third_party_destruction"=>"NA"}, "action"=>"update", "controller"=>"jobs", "id"=>"17"}
```

Can anybody shed some light as to why `params[:job]` is not including any attributes?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: maybe some before_filter? it's just blind guessing with only that code, the form sends the data, something is removing it before entering your action

Comment: That's exactly what the problem was. I had a before_filter I had forgotten to remove. Many thanks for your help.